# Apply changes of CAAnimation while animating

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview, core-animation

I want to animate an `UIView` with a given `CAAnimation` and interact with the view while it's animating (the view has a gesture recognizer).

If I understand correctly `CAAnimation` only animates the view's layer, but the view itself will remain in the original position.

How can I make the `UIView` move with the `CAAnimation`?

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about visual "stickiness" you can do:

```
[myAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
```

But this is only visual. It doesn't change the actual layer's properties.

If you want the layer's properties to be updated to new values also, you can do something like:

```
// You have code above that to register the property you want to animate...
[myAnimation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
[myAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
```

Comment: No, I care about user interaction. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than attempting to move it, you could expand your `UIView` to cover the area you want to receive touches in, and then animate its `layer` within it.  Make sure to set the view `opaque` property to `NO`.
You may want to add a `sublayer` to `view.layer` rather than moving the view's own layer, for example if you want the layer to go outside the bounds of the view without affecting the layout of subviews of the view.

Comment: It would be useful to know why this was down-voted, not to mention good etiquete.
I think it is a valid approach, without knowing exactly what the questioner is trying to achieve.